# Tamejs can't work with mocha?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, tamejs

See my test code using mocha + tamejs:

**test/t.tjs**

```
require('should');

function inc(n, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('### inc: ' + n);
    callback(n+1);
  }, 1000);
};

describe('test', function(){
  it('show ok with tamejs', function(){
     console.log('### testing ...');
     var result;
     await { inc(1, defer(result)); }
     console.log('result: ' + result);
     result.should.equal(123456); // won't pass
  });
});
```

Compile it to t.js:

```
tamejs -o test/t.js test/t.tjs
```

Run mocha

```
mocha
```

Result:

```
### testing ...
.

✔ 1 test complete (1ms)
```

It seems the `inc` method has never been invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is I didn't use mocha correctly.

It should be wrote as:

```
describe('test', function(){
  it('show ok with tamejs', function(done){
     console.log('### testing ...');
     var result;
     await { inc(1, defer(result)); }
     console.log('result: ' + result);
     result.should.equal(123456); // won't pass
     done();
  });
});
```

Please notice the `done`, it used in mocha to determine if a asynchronous invocation has finished or not. Without it, mocha won't wait for the asynchronous invocation.